Flet how to use data in assets folder
I'm trying to build my first Flet App. In order for my script to work, I need to read in data (e.g. Pandas-DataFrames as Pickle-Files) and I also import functions from separate scripts (not the main.py script). I would later like to compile the App using the build command, so tried placing all files and scripts in subdirectories of the assets folder of my Flet project. However, I don't get how to correctly specify the filepaths later in my script. Does anyone know how to correctly do this?
I tried the following, but it won't work when running the App via the run command.
def main(page: ft.Page):

    data_path = '/data/data.pkl'
    df = pd.read_pickle(filepath_or_buffer = data_path)

    from assets.scripts.gui_plots import ErrorHist


ft.app(target = main, assets_dir = 'assets')


If you place the file in the same folder as your project and import it normally, it should also work with the build command.
Recently, I created a program in Flet that uses another Python file. By simply adding import file in the main.py, it worked perfectly with the build command. The file was located in the same directory as main.py.
Also, just try to delete the leaning “/“ of /data at the beginning if you’re going to place it in assets folder. Just put data_path = 'data/data.pkl'. When using the assets folder, you should set the path as if your program is inside that folder.
Hope this helps you!

Thank you very much, this helps a lot

So I tried changing the filepaths. Say I've got a DataFrame stored as a pkl-File with the following path: 'C:/flet_project/assets/data/data.pkl'. The filepath main.py-script is 'C:/flet_project/main.py'. When I specify the variable data_path in the code above as "data/data.pkl" and try running the app via Flet's run command, the file isn't found, so unfortunately it doesn't work. Using images placed in the assets folder using Flet's Image-control works fine.

Have you tried setting assets/data/data.pk? If it's not a control in Flet, maybe the assets folder doesn't work properly.
